# Cluster point for net with projection map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know this is a hard question for those they have strong background in net in topology. I hope some one will be to help.

Show that if $(x_\alpha)$ is a net in $\displaystyle\prod_{\gamma\in\Delta}X_{\gamma}$ having $x$ as cluster point then $\big(\pi_{\gamma}(x_{\alpha})\big)$ has $\pi(x)$ as a cluster point in $X_\gamma$

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999568/cluster-points-in-products?rq=1.